# Need help understanding how Eclipse IProgressMonitor works

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse IProgressMonitor to monitor the progress of a task. There are four steps, and I write the following code.

```java
int totalWork = 100;
String message = "Compiling " + inputFile.getName();
monitor.beginTask(message, totalWork);
monitor.subTask(message + " - first pass");

...// Work
monitor.worked(25);

if (monitor.isCanceled())
    return;         

monitor.subTask(message + " - invoking");

...// work
monitor.worked(25);

if (monitor.isCanceled())           
    return;

monitor.subTask(message + " - second pass");
...// Work
monitor.worked(25);

if (monitor.isCanceled())
    return;

monitor.subTask(message + " - final pass");
...// Work
monitor.worked(25);

if (monitor.isCanceled())
    return;

monitor.done();
```

As I have total work 100, and each step increase it by 25, I am hoping to see the progress bar show 25% 50% etc. and increase. However the progress bar stops at some number (33%, 38%, 20%, kind of random on different machines) and does  not change until the entire job is done. The task name changes though. I read the JavaDoc for this API and follow the way it suggests (I think). Can anyone help tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Where is this code? In a Job?

Comment: In an implementation of ``IncrementalProjectBuilder``